# Windows 7 Blue Screen caused by hal.dll

Tags: windows-7, crash

I have a Windows 7 home edition x64 computer that runs 24/7 as it runs Windows Media center on multiple extenders I have through out the house. Recently I have been getting more frequent blue screens that are caused by the **hal.dll** see below:
[image]

After a google search I found that **hal.dll** is

> Windows Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL), a file that hides hardware
> complexities from Windows applications. hal.dll is a system process
> that is needed for your PC to work properly.

This is very vague and doesn't help me solve the bluescreen problem.

**How can I stop the hal.dll from crashing my computer?**

Comment: Next time please post those parameters shown in the picture so I don't have to type them out. :) http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-7-is-encountering-a-blue-screen/6a9b24cd-77fc-440c-ae7f-a03c85107a6e <-- according to that you might consider reinstalling a wireless Intel NIC driver.

Comment: If you can drop the crash minidump online somewhere, I can run it through WinDbg to attempt to discover the faulting module.

Comment: First things first, run a chkdsk on the hard drive to be sure it is not file corruption of the hal.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hal.dll` might the culprit that's showing up in logs, but this is very likely a hardware issue (failing parts or incompatability), or driver issues which aren't being detected until the drivers pass control back up to the abstraction layer.

Make sure all your drivers are up to date for the affected systems, and if possible run diagnostics on the hardware to verify that it's fully functioning.

Comment: +1. On the other hand, a newer driver may be the cause, albeit less likely. Something to consider while troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

hal.dll does stand for hardware abstraction layer and it is the base driver which allows a processor to communicate with the motherboard efficiently.   Different versions are provided for the type of processor, and it is difficult to change the driver.  Usually formatting outweights the cost of troubleshooting.   And it likely to come if there is a hardware issue, but I have also seen hal.dll become corrupt.

You can try a recovery first.. [Microsoft Windows 7 Recovery Options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/What-are-the-system-recovery-options-in-Windows-7)